# Multiple domains pointing to the same folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, multiple-domains

I am currently running two websites. I am able to add my domains and set the root folder to / instead of /domain1.com and /domain2.com. That way both websites go to the same folder, however they both maintain their domain names (no redirects). My code determines whether the user is from domain1.com or domain2.com and displays the appropriate content using PHP.

Now, I have switched to another web hoster. The problem is that they don't allow you to specify where the root folder is: so it has to be /domain1.com and /domain2.com. They also don't seem to allow access to httpd.conf to edit VirtualHosts.

I have tried using .htaccess to do a redirect, but the problem is that when I go to domain2.com, it redirects straight to domain1.com, and it doesn't keep its host name of domain2.com.

I have also tried setting up symlinks, but it seems to be doing the exact same thing.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do a rewrite rule similar to the following (don't trust my syntax)?

```
# if domain2.com, send all requests to domain1.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../domain1.com/index.php/$1
```

So if someone does go to `domain2.com`, all requests are passed through the `index.php` file on `domain1.com` for processing (I presume you're doing something similar already).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up symbolic links using ssh that don't redirect to the other domain. I have several .co.uk domains that use the same data as the .com that don't redirect. What host is it? You should be able to do this, maybe email them asking why it redirects.

Sure it's not in the htaccess file to redirect the domain2.com to domain1.com?